# How match output (pred value) to input value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predictive-modeling, data, numpy

I'm working with data(with 4 columns which are p(product), M(name of the store)), I want predict the demand of store for that I sued SVR on the data by theses formulation:

```
dfn = pd.get_dummies(df)
x = dfn.drop(["demand"],axis=1)
y = dfn.demand
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
dfn = scaler.fit_transform(dfn)
.
.
.
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
pred = regressor.predict(testX)
SVM_R2 = print('r2= ' +str(r2_score(testY,pred)))
print(pred)
# array example is between 0 and 1
array = np.array(pred)
#scaled from 200 to 800
minimo = 200
maximo = 800
output=array * minimo + (maximo - minimo)
print(output)
df2=pd.DataFrame(output)
df2.to_excel(r'/content/Book1.xlsx', index = False)
```

and now I get the output of this prediction. My question is, how can I match these outputs to inputs, or how can I found which demands are related to each market?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code and get output from this(with the help of Oxbowerce).

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(testX,columns=['p','M','Date'])
df3=pd.DataFrame(pred,columns=['pred'])
df4=pd.concat([df2,df3],axis=1)
df4.to_excel(r'/content/Book1.xlsx', index = False)
```

I saved the output in an excel file. You can see in the below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The outputs of your model are in the same order as your inputs, so the first row in your `output` array corresponds to the first row in the `testX` array. If you want to have both the inputs and the model prediction in one table you can just concatenate them along the column axis.

Comment: I can't use this, because if you look at the pictures which I attached, you find that the size of data after using is different from the main (when split into train and test sets).